# wireshark installing ubuntu14.0.4 error

Tags: wireshark

I am trying to install by:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/programs-ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install wireshark
$ sudo apt-get remove wireshark
```

However, I got the below problem when running `wireshark`:

```
wireshark: symbol lookup error: wireshark: undefined symbol: wslua_reload_plugins
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem, the following solution worked for me - delete the following files.

```
/usr/local/lib/libwsutil.so.*

/usr/local/lib/libwireshark.so.*

/usr/local/lib/libwiretap.so.*
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks it works ( i like the new interface). However, I face with another problem that as soon as I start wireshark, I can't access intertnet anymore ( even the wireless card still says connected)

Comment: I have no problem when capturing packets, but while running wireshark, I can access internet somehow.